# Texture coordinates for rendering a 3d sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, texture-mapping

I am drawing a 3d sphere using `GL_QUAD_STRIP` primitive and it works except I don't know how to set up the texture coordinates.

I have a certain number of `division` that divide my sphere into  equal number of latitudes and longitudes. Hence, the sphere's vertices are approximated using the divisions as follows

```
   float x, y, z, dTheta=180/divisions, dLon=360/divisions, degToRad=3.14/180 ;

    for(float lat =0 ; lat <=180 ; lat+=dTheta)
    {
        glBegin( GL_QUAD_STRIP ) ;
        for(float lon = 0 ; lon <=360; lon+=dLon)
        {  

            x = r*cosf(lat * degToRad) * sinf(lon * degToRad) ;
            y = r*sinf(lat * degToRad) * sinf(lon * degToRad) ;
            z = r*cosf(lon * degToRad) ;

            glNormal3f( x, y, z) ;
            glVertex3f( x, y, z ) ;

            x = r*cosf((lat + dTheta) * degToRad) * sinf(lon * degToRad) ;
            y = r*sinf((lat + dTheta) * degToRad) * sinf(lon * degToRad) ;
            z = r*cosf( lon * degToRad ) ;

            glNormal3f( x, y, z ) ;
            glVertex3f( x, y, z ) ;
        }
        glEnd() ;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem was that I was only drawing 2 vertices and `GL_QUAD_STRIP` requires 4. The following code now has both vertices set up properly and texture working

```
   double x, y, z, dTheta=180/divisions, dLon=360/divisions, degToRad=3.141592665885/180 ;

    for(double lat =0; lat <=180; lat+=dTheta)
    {

        glBegin( GL_QUAD_STRIP ) ;
        for(double lon =0 ; lon <=360 ; lon+=dLon)
        {  


            //Vertex 1
            x = r*cos(lon * degToRad) * sin(lat * degToRad) ;
            y = r*sin(lon * degToRad) * sin(lat * degToRad) ;
            z = r*cos(lat * degToRad) ;
            glNormal3d( x, y, z) ;
            glTexCoord2d(lon/360-0.25, lat/180);
            glVertex3d( x, y, z ) ;


            //Vetex 2
            x = r*cos(lon * degToRad) * sin( (lat + dTheta)* degToRad) ;
            y = r*sin(lon * degToRad) * sin((lat + dTheta) * degToRad) ;
            z = r*cos( (lat + dTheta) * degToRad ) ;
            glNormal3d( x, y, z ) ;
            glTexCoord2d(lon/360-0.25, (lat + dTheta-1)/(180)); 
            glVertex3d( x, y, z ) ;


            //Vertex 3
            x = r*cos((lon + dLon) * degToRad) * sin((lat) * degToRad) ;
            y = r*sin((lon + dLon) * degToRad) * sin((lat) * degToRad) ;
            z = r*cos((lat) * degToRad ) ;
            glNormal3d( x, y, z ) ;
           glTexCoord2d((lon + dLon)/(360)-0.25 ,(lat)/180);
             glVertex3d( x, y, z ) ;


            //Vertex 4
            x = r*cos((lon + dLon) * degToRad) * sin((lat + dTheta)* degToRad) ;
            y = r*sin((lon + dLon)* degToRad) * sin((lat + dTheta)* degToRad) ;
            z = r*cos((lat + dTheta)* degToRad ) ;
            glNormal3d( x, y, z ) ;
            glTexCoord2d((lon + dLon)/360-0.25, (lat + dTheta)/(180));
             glVertex3d( x, y, z ) ;


        }
        glEnd() ;

    }
```

Hope people who get stuck may find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you used standardly distortioned sphere texture (like usual earth map) you should use texture coordinates like (lat/180, lon/360), i.e. normalized values in range [0..1].

Answer (score 0):

Add new variables :

```
float texX = 0.0;
float texy = 0.0;
float dTex = 1/ divisions;
```

then add then to the loop :
   float x, y, z, dTheta=180/divisions, dLon=360/divisions, degToRad=3.14/180 ;

```
for(float lat =0 ; lat <=180 ; lat+=dTheta, texX += dTex)
{
    texY = 0.0;
    glBegin( GL_QUAD_STRIP ) ;
    for(float lon = 0 ; lon <=360; lon+=dLon, texY += dTex )
    {  

        x = r*cosf(lat * degToRad) * sinf(lon * degToRad) ;
        y = r*sinf(lat * degToRad) * sinf(lon * degToRad) ;
        z = r*cosf(lon * degToRad) ;

        glNormal3f( x, y, z) ;
        glTexCoord2f( texX, texY );
        glVertex3f( x, y, z ) ;
    }
    glEnd() ;

}
```

Comment: That didnt work. It drew the whole sphere of a brown sort of color. It is not at all wrapping my sample image which is a checkers (chess board layout) picture

Comment: @ladiesMan217 Have you created, and enabled textures?