# Android OpenGL ES textured half sphere

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have to develop an equirectangular image viewer, like the one of the [Ricoh Theta app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theta).

I'm doing it on Android, with Open GL ES (1.0, but I can change to 2.0 if needed).

For now, I have managed to create the half sphere (based on [this answer](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/159402-half-sphere)), with this code:

```
public class HalfSphere {

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // region Attributes

    private final int[] mTextures = new int[1];

    float[][] mVertices;
    int mNbStrips;
    int mNbVerticesPerStrips;

    private final List<FloatBuffer> mVerticesBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<ByteBuffer> mIndicesBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<FloatBuffer> mTextureBuffer = new ArrayList<>();

    // endregion
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // region Constructor

    public HalfSphere(int nbStrips, int nbVerticesPerStrips, float radius) {

        // Generate the vertices:
        mNbStrips = nbStrips;
        mNbVerticesPerStrips = nbVerticesPerStrips;
        mVertices = new float[mNbStrips * mNbVerticesPerStrips][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < mNbStrips; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < mNbVerticesPerStrips; j++) {

                mVertices[i * mNbVerticesPerStrips + j][0] = (float) (radius * Math.cos(j * 2 * Math.PI / mNbVerticesPerStrips) * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / mNbStrips));
                mVertices[i * mNbVerticesPerStrips + j][1] = (float) (radius * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / mNbStrips));
                mVertices[i * mNbVerticesPerStrips + j][2] = (float) (radius * Math.sin(j * 2 * Math.PI / mNbVerticesPerStrips) * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / mNbStrips));
            }
        }

        // Populate the buffers:
        for(int i = 0; i < mNbStrips - 1; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < mNbVerticesPerStrips; j++) {

                byte[] indices = {
                        0, 1, 2,  // first triangle (bottom left - top left - top right)
                        0, 2, 3   // second triangle (bottom left - top right - bottom right)
                };

                float[] p1 = mVertices[i * mNbVerticesPerStrips + j];
                float[] p2 = mVertices[i * mNbVerticesPerStrips + (j + 1) % mNbVerticesPerStrips];
                float[] p3 = mVertices[(i + 1) * mNbVerticesPerStrips + (j + 1) % mNbVerticesPerStrips];
                float[] p4 = mVertices[(i + 1) * mNbVerticesPerStrips + j];

                float[] quad = {
                        p1[0], p1[1], p1[2],
                        p2[0], p2[1], p2[2],
                        p3[0], p3[1], p3[2],
                        p4[0], p4[1], p4[2]
                };

                mVerticesBuffer.add(floatArrayToFloatBuffer(quad));
                mTextureBuffer.add(floatArrayToFloatBuffer(quad));
                mIndicesBuffer.add(byteArrayToByteBuffer(indices));
            }
        }
    }

    // endregion
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // region Draw

    public void draw(final GL10 gl) {

        // bind the previously generated texture.
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.mTextures[0]);

        // Point to our buffers.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        // Set the face rotation, clockwise in this case.
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        for(int i = 0; i < mVerticesBuffer.size(); i++) {

            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVerticesBuffer.get(i));
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer.get(i));

            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mIndicesBuffer.get(i)); // GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP / GL_LINE_LOOP
        }

        // Disable the client state before leaving.
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    // endregion
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // region Utils

    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Bitmap texture) {
        // Generate one texture pointer, and bind it to the texture array.
        gl.glGenTextures(1, this.mTextures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.mTextures[0]);

        // Create nearest filtered texture.
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, texture, 0);
        texture.recycle();
    }

    public FloatBuffer floatArrayToFloatBuffer(float[] array) {

        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(array.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());    // use the device hardware's native byte order
        FloatBuffer fb = vbb.asFloatBuffer();  // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        fb.put(array);    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        fb.position(0);      // set the buffer to read the first coordinate

        return fb;
    }

    public ByteBuffer byteArrayToByteBuffer(byte[] array) {

        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(array.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());    // use the device hardware's native byte order
        vbb.put(array);    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vbb.position(0);      // set the buffer to read the first coordinate

        return vbb;
    }

    // endregion
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Of course, the texture is not applied correctly, as I'm using the coordinates of my vertices. Does someone see how to do it correctly? I'll also need to be able to "move" the texture when the user pan.

EDIT: as suggested by codetiger, doing lat/180 and lon/360, and then normalizing to [0..1] worked. Now, I'm trying to add the panning. It works when panning on longitude (horizontally):

[image: longitude panning]

But not when panning on latitude (vertically):

[image]

I'm simply adding values between 0..1 when the user pans. I tried to use the formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) with no success. Any idea?

If it helps, that's what I want (obtained with the Ricoh Theta app):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the sphere a full 360 degree sphere, you can replace the lines below.

```
mVertices[i * mNbVerticesPerStrips + j][0] = (float) (radius * Math.cos(j * 2 * Math.PI / mNbVerticesPerStrips) * Math.cos(2 * i * Math.PI / mNbStrips));
mVertices[i * mNbVerticesPerStrips + j][1] = (float) (radius * Math.sin(2 * i * Math.PI / mNbStrips));
mVertices[i * mNbVerticesPerStrips + j][2] = (float) (radius * Math.sin(j * 2 * Math.PI / mNbVerticesPerStrips) * Math.cos(2 * i * Math.PI / mNbStrips));
```

The only change is using `2 * Math.PI / mNbStrips` for second angle instead of `Math.PI / mNbStrips`

And to rotate the image, you can rotate the sphere by using

```
gl.glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Update:
To get correct Texture Coordinates for the sphere, for standard distortion sphere texture you can use (lat/180, lon/360) and normalise it to get [0..1]. As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10395141/409315

Comment: Thanks, but the half sphere is what I need, in order to be able to "unzoom" (= display the half sphere farther). With a sphere if I get "out" of the sphere, the result is not what I want. The question is really: how to apply a texture to my half sphere?

Comment: Yes this way it works. But now I have trouble with the latitude panning (see my edits).

Comment: Actually, I think you cannot pan on latitude for a equirectangular projection image. This will create distortion.

Comment: It is possible, and it works perfectly when I map the texture on a complete sphere. The texture is like this one: http://blog.topazlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Screen-Shot-2013-12-11-at-10.42.18-AM.png

Comment: I think I need to divide something by 2 somewhere, as I am using a half sphere, but I can't see where...

Comment: I think it is not lon/360, instead it should be lon/180 as it is half sphere

Comment: No, this does not work. When wrapping the texture on a complete sphere, half part of the texture is mapped on a half sphere, and the other part of the texture on the other half of the sphere. I guess I need to reproduce this behavior, but I'm stuck. The other option would be to use a complete sphere and display only a half. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: That will be simple, OpenGL ES will already remove the backfaces and will only render half the sphere. But you have to reverse the order of triangles so that the normals face inwards.

Comment: Great! Do you have an example (for removing the backfaces, not for reversing the triangles)?

Comment: glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);

Comment: Use these 3 functions to select which side of the faces to cull. Usually the last function glFrontFace defines which order to remove, so you can just change the argument to GL_CCW to see which one work for you

Comment: Good Luck @TimAutin

Comment: Thanks! A last (I hope) question: it works when using a sphere that I found on the web, but with mine, on one face all the triangles are displayed (which is fine), but on the other, only half the triangles are culled. An idea why? I tried specifying my quad in all the possible combinations, still the same problem. Do I need to specify the 6 coordinates and use glDrawArrays, or is it possible to do it with glDrawElements and my quads?

Comment: OK I got it, I had to change my indices order. Thanks again!!